# Range validation not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

We have written as below lines of code

```
<div class="controls">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPort" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator   CausesValidation="true"    ID="rfvprot"     runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter port number." ControlToValidate ="txtPort">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
 <asp:RangeValidator   CausesValidation="true"    ID="RVPort" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter value between 1 to 65000" ControlToValidate ="txtPort" MinimumValue ="1" MaximumValue ="65000"></asp:RangeValidator>
</div>
```

If we enter value 667 or any value, then click on submit button, it still displays the validation message.

Comment: Does you submit button include `CausesValidation="true"`?

Comment: It is working now by adding CausesValidation="true" to submit button... Thankyou

Comment: @user2179026 : Post your Button markup also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `CausesValidation="true"` to your submit button.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried add `Type="Integer"` attribute to range validator

Answer (score 0):

You can try and add a type to the RangeValidator

```
 <asp:RangeValidator Type="Double"  OR
 <asp:RangeValidator Type="Integer"
```